# How to run 5 Shell job Simultaneous and keep rest in Queue?

Tags: multithreading, shell, unix, ksh

While both "Task Spooler" and "at" handle multiple queues and allow the execution of commands at a later point, the at project handles output from commands by emailing the results to the user who queued the command, while Task Spooler allows you to get at the results from the command line instead.

But what I am looking for is a way that would allow me to run 5 jobs simultaneously and keep rest of the jobs in a queue, so when any one of the 5 is over it would start the next one.

So, if 5 jobs running and 4 more in the queue as soon as any of them is finished, the next one would start executing and again 5 jobs would running simultaneously.

is there a way to handle such task?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using task spooler you can do what you're asking. Use the `-S <number>` flag to specify the number of "slots" (jobs that run concurrently). You can even use `-D <job id>` to make different jobs depend on another specific job's completion.

So in your example, if you set `tsp -S 5`, task spooler would run the first 5 jobs and queue up the next 4. Once one of the original 5 jobs completed, the next queued up job (based on lowest job id) would then begin. This would continue to happen as running jobs finish and more slots open up.

Also note for anyone else reading this, on Ubuntu (and maybe other Debian-based systems) task spooler is called `tsp` so as not to conflict with the openssl-ts tool. On most other systems it should called just `ts`. Which is why even on Ubuntu, task spooler will refer to itself as `ts`.

From the manual, regarding slots:

```
MULTI-SLOT
       ts by default offers a queue where each job runs only after the previous finished.  Nevertheless, you can  change  the
       maximum  number  of jobs running at once with the -S [num] parameter. We call that number the amount of slots. You can
       also set the initial number of jobs with the environment variable TS_SLOTS .  When  increasing  this  setting,  queued
       waiting  jobs  will  be run at once until reaching the maximum set. When decreasing this setting, no other job will be
       run until it can meet the amount of running jobs set.   When using an amount of slots greater than 1,  the  action  of
       some  commands may change a bit. For example, -t without jobid will tail the first job running, and -d will try to set
       the dependency with the last job added.

       -S [num]
              Set the maximum amount of running jobs at once. If you don't specify num it will return the maximum  amount  of
              running jobs set.
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends of course how you want to start your tasks. But lets assume they are loop based. The following would launch all `N` commands in the background.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for i in {1..N}; do
   # do awesome command based on $i
   command $i &
done
wait
```

So if you want to launch only 5 jobs, you need to keep track of what is running :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

Njobs=5

for i in {1..N}; do
   # Checks how many jobs are currently running
   while [[ $(jobs -p | wc -l) > $Njobs ]]; do
     sleep 0.1
   done

   # do awesome command based on $i
   command $i &
done
wait
```

Answer (score 2):

You have already a tool that does this: [GNU Parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)

```
parallel --jobs 4 bash ::: script1.sh script2.sh script3.sh script4.sh
```

See [Parallel tutorial](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html) for examples.

For the case where fewer jobs than tasks run:

```
for f in $(seq $TASKS); do
    echo ${RANDOM}e-04
done | parallel --jobs $JOBS "echo {#} {}; sleep {}"
```

Example results for `TASKS=9`:

```
JOBS=1        JOBS=5
1 17994e-04   4 2844e-04
2 25155e-04   2 5752e-04
3 7859e-04    3 13084e-04
4 11812e-04   1 13749e-04
5 19851e-04   8 2546e-04
6 1568e-04    7 12086e-04
7 24074e-04   6 16087e-04
8 8435e-04    9 9826e-04
9 1407e-04    5 27257e-04
```